# C Project but pmap shows libstdc++ loaded

Tags: c, memory

I am learning gui dev using gtk3 library with c. One thing I have noticed is that this lib seems to load c++ standard library during runtime. I am not quite sure what's happening here as I have already checked that I am using the gcc compiler, not the g++ one! Here is the pmap (with grep) output:

```
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode  Mapping
00007fe342236000     600     600       0 r---- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007fe3422cc000     964     612       0 r-x-- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007fe3423bd000     292      60       0 r---- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007fe342406000       4       0       0 ----- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007fe342407000      44      44      44 r---- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
00007fe342412000      12      12      12 rw--- libstdc++.so.6.0.28
```

Comment: The library itself may be partly written in C++ even though you use a C API.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for the answer.

Comment: It's just a theory though.